# Is it Create-React-App2 suits for bigger application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have the big react application, Have done from the scratch.Have added more webpack loaders and plugins(For code split and compress) in webpack.config file. Now planning to use Create-React-App2 for this application so is it possible to do all configuration(code split and compress) in create-react-app2? Is it better to migrate create-React-App2 for big created application?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference, what the `create-react-app2` does is building react dependencies, which you could do by yourself even when using the original `create-react-app`, but it will take needless effort.
by saying "dependencies" I mean libraries and frameworks that makes the react programming easier, it doesn't have dependencies of its own.

for more information: [create-react-app2 - what's new](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html#whats-new)